# Are there any math algorithms that are conducive to good responsive html design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm sick of guessing at what percentages, I need to use with `(x) amount of divs` and other elements in the flow of my design. I want to know what sort of math goes into determining `if <div class=element1>` is scaled down `10%`, `<div class=element2>` needs to be scaled `(x)%` to maintain `2%` gap. Not sure how else to phrase this question. I know there is bootstrap, but I'm curious to what sort of math they use to keep it all so responsive.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Basic arithmetic? Percentages are not complicated.

Comment: I guess what math goes into making your html responsive. I find myself guessing and at what percentages I need to use for width and height when getting my layout to look the way I want to.

Comment: If you are bothered by paddings or borders use the css property box-sizing:border-box;    :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, I'm going to clarify some assumptions. Be sure to correct any of them if they're incorrect.

1. You're working with a design that has a fixed gutter between columns.
2. You're not using bootstrap.

Your best bet is to use a fixed pixel or em based gutter if you'd like to have better control. This is how Bootstrap does it.

```
.col {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.col:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

If you're concerned with aspect ratios of images or elements, you can try to the following:

```
.element-with-aspect-ratio {
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; // if not set globally
    padding-bottom: 33.33%; // For a 3:1 aspect ratio
}
```

My preferred way to do this is .column > .element-with-aspect-ratio

The math for a grid shouldn't be too complex. Check out this guide by Chris Coyier.
https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

Comment: Did you make an account just to answer this question made by a guy who made an account just to ask this question? This is a pretty neat exchange going on here hahaha

Comment: Thanks! I've tried looking through the CSS files in bootstrap, but it's pretty overwhelming as I'm not so proficient in css

Comment: Haha I've had the account for years. Just figured I'd start using it. Edited answer with more substance.

Comment: I tried to fix your CSS formatting with an edit to help you out, but you just wiped out that change.

Comment: No problem @SavageryDigital. Please mark it as the correct answer if it helped you.

Comment: Apologies, @jfriend00 - I made another edit. Ill fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @TylerUntisz Please don't tell the asker to accept your (or any other) answer just 20 minutes after the question was posted. It's better to wait until you've had a few answers and everyone (including the people in other timezones) has had a chance to look at your question before deciding which answer is best.

Comment: Got it. I'm a rookie and should probably acquaint myself with SOP before posting much more. Thanks.